# Weird behaviour of C-A of vim?

Tags: vim

The behavior of vim's <kbd>Ctrl A</kbd> is weird when incrementing **numbers <= 0.005**.

Due to some personal need, I want to get a set of numbers that increments by 0.005 each time from 0.005,
like this:

```
0.005
0.010
0.015
...
```

then I thought of vim's macro and <kbd>Ctrl A</kbd>.

I entered 0.005 in vim's first line, use <kbd>y y p Ctrl A</kbd> to record a macro. But when I moved the cursor to 5 and then pressed <kbd>Ctrl A</kbd> continuously, the **third** time, the number changed directly **from 0.007 to 0.010**. If I just press 3 times, the output will become:

```
0.005
0.010
0.013
0.016
...
```

That means that I cannot complete the task using vim.

After doing this in other ways, I started to be interested in the behavior of vim's <kbd>Ctrl A</kbd>.

The text below comes from vim's help manual:

`:h CTRL-A`:

```
Add [count] to the number or alphabetic character at or after the cursor.
```

and `:h count`:

```
An optional number that may precede the command to multiply or iterate the command.
If no number is given, a count of one is used, unless otherwise noted.
```

When I tested some other numbers, I found that the behavior becomes weird starting from 0.01. But I still don't know why <kbd>Ctrl A</kbd> behaves like this.

Before starting to read the source of vim, does anyone know why vim's <kbd>Ctrl A</kbd> behaves like this on decimals?

BTW, My PC environment is Win10, and I use vim_only_x64 downloading from vim's official site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Simson Said, vim thinks it is an octal number and increses 0.07 to 0.10.
You can change this behavior by telling vim not to use octal numbers.

```
:set nrformats-=octal
```

Then it increases as expected 0.09 => 0.10

You can see the definition o numbers with `:h expr-number`

Comment: But it will still consider it only as one integer and increment from 0.99 to 0.100

Comment: Yes you are rigth, in fact it interprets it as to integers seperated by a dot

Answer (score 2):

Vim does not recognize `0.004` as a **decimal fraction**, it interpreters it as  `something.004` The leading 0 of a number encodes an [**octal**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) number so it increments from 007 to 010

Fun fact it will also recognize hexadecimal numbers `0x09` will be incremented to `0x0a`